# Calculate the probability of getting this hand in n tries

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, card-games, probability-theory

Imagine there is a card game where the primary objective of the game is to get 4 of one card in your hand.

#### Game mechanics

Each player starts of with 10 cards in their hand. The remaining 32 cards (jokers are taken out of the deck) are put in the center.

Each turn, a player can put one of their cards (*which is chosen at random*) at the bottom of the deck and draw one from the top. They roll a fair, six sided die to determine how many times they do this in one turn.

#### Card notation

As Penguino helpfully pointed out, suite is irrelevant, so cards are numbered 1 - 13, where 1 is Ace and 13 is King.

Write a program that takes in two arguments: Each players starting hand and Number of turns and return the probability that a player will get four of the same number in your hand within n turns.

### Examples to try

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4],10]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will do this.

Comment: As the suite of each card in the hand is completely irrelevant to the probability of getting a 4 of a kind, can you simplify the card notation to the suite-less 2,3,4...10,J,Q,K,A? or even simpler 1,2,3...10,11,12,13